# Stop Apple ID change address page from kicking me out

Tags: apple-id

I'm having troubles with my Apple ID. Apart from not being able to download apps, I can't change my Apple ID details through the iPhone, and especially when I log in to appleid.apple.com and trying to edit my address, I get logged out getting an "unknown error" message.

Any ideas what to do?

Edit - Nor can I connect to the iTunes store too see my details within the App Store app. "Can't connect to iTunes store"

Comment: Did you try to access the site on a computer?

Answer (score 1):

Amazingly, that last edit made me search and find answer explained here and on other places: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1447069&page=4

Not only changing the date, but first signing out of iTunes from Settings, then change date to manual to something in the future (2014 in my case), try to access App Store through the app again, it fails, then change back the date to automatic, log in to App Store. And voila, now it works.

Edit - However, the address page started working mainly because the browser turned from my native Swedish into English. In the English version it works, in Swedish it doesn't.